# Test disabling of button using Vue Test Utils

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

How do you test a button's disabled attribute changing in vue test utils? The disabled attribute of the button depends on isFormValid and isFormModified. I've tried setting them to both true in my test, but it still receives a false.

Component

```
 <v-btn
   data-qa="reviewData"
   @click="validateForm()"
   :disabled="!(isFormValid && isFormModified)"
   :color="primaryColor"
   rounded
   class="font-weight-regular text-none white--text px-7 mr-8 mt-3"
 >
   { $t('accountMaintenance.review') }}</v-btn
```

Test

```
wrapper.setData({ isFormModified: true, isFormValid: true })
const button = wrapper.find('[data-qa="reviewData"]')
expect(button.attributes().disabled).toBe('false')
```